# Jquery is not working if page is opend in popup

Tags: jquery, popup

We have one page that has a "jQuery" `document.ready` script function. It is working fine if we were to browse it in a new tab. But when we try the same page in a Popup the script does not work (document.ready).

The following function is used to open the popup in SharePoint 2013 Online.

aspx code:

```
<a  href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/NewForm.aspx');">MyPage</a>`
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ctl00_ctl41_g_9efece1f_fded_45df_a1be_364581e26f60_ff4_1_ctl00_DropDownChoice').change(function() {
       if($(this).val() == 'New Collection Concept')
         {
           $('#updateCollection').hide();
           $('#newCollection').show();
         }
       else
         {
           $('#newCollection').hide();
           $('#updateCollection').show();
         }
     });
```

Comment: Can you post the full method call line, with parameters you are passing

Comment: Hi Unnin i have added all code please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @Unnie Maybe this is for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453303/javascript-pop-up-window-document-is-never-ready

Comment: Is this new code opened in new iframe? or as new DOM element?

Answer (score 1):

can you try window.onLoad function instead (like iframe).

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('#ctl00_ctl41_g_9efece1f_fded_45df_a1be_364581e26f60_ff4_1_ctl00_DropDownChoice').change(function() {
   if($(this).val() == 'New Collection Concept')
     {
       $('#updateCollection').hide();
       $('#newCollection').show();
     }
   else
     {
       $('#newCollection').hide();
       $('#updateCollection').show();
     }

};
```

i could be wrong but i belive that the dom is already ready as its not a parent element but rather a child element of the parent that returns the document ready! otherwise create a iframe and use onload or document ready within that!